# Old passport number mentioned in visa for Kuwait

Tags: visas, passports, paperwork, indian-citizens, kuwait

I am living in India and I applied for an employment visa from Kuwait. I got all visa documents now, but my old passport number is mentioned in all documents. I renewed my passport and it has a new passport number. Is there any problem in travelling to Kuwait with my existing visa?

Answer (score 6):

### If you have your old passport with you:

No problem. You still can use the visa as long as you bring both passports. Even if the passport is cancelled (clipped).

### If you do not have your old passport with you:

Big problem, you need to visit the Kuwaiti embassy to issue a new visa.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is correct. I'm quite sure that even if you have your old passport and the new passport does not explicitly state it replaces the old passport, mentioning it by its number, it will not work.

Comment: I'd call that embassy anyway to confirm whether this is correct or not. Cheaper and more peace of mind than fretting over whether you'll be allowed through customs upon arrival...

Comment: If not have old passport you can also go to the passport issuing authority ( minister, consulate ) and ask for an official document stating that new passport No.xxx was given in lieu / to replace old passport   No.YYY . This is an official document generally accepted in most countries / border controls . I have used it myself for a Driver's licence .

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is. Due to unobservant officials, you might be able to get away with this, but, having visa documents made out for a passport you will not be traveling with will simply mean that the visa documents will not apply to the passport you have, thus that your visa won't apply to you.